# Break when order data in column C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, break

I have data grid view like this

[image]

When I try to click the column header trying to order the data, the program breaks on line

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
```

**ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled.
Index was out of range. 
Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

Here's the code in .designer.cs

```
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Azure;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 62);
this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(586, 381);
this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 9;
this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1);
```

and here's the code in my .cs

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
            groupBoxPenghuni.Visible = false;
            groupBoxStaff.Visible = false;
            groupBoxRoom.Visible = false;
            groupBoxDPenghuni.Visible = true;
            groupBoxPenghasilan.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_AddResident_Resident.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_AddResident_Room.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_AddResident1.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_DeleteResident_Resident.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_DeleteResident1.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_Resident.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_Update_Room.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_UpdateResident1.Visible = false;
        }
```

What's the fault? And what should I do?

Comment: what exception you are getting ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar
ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled. 
Index was out of range. 
Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index.

I have edited my post. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it fails is because your `dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1` is firing sometime when you sort and the `Index was out of range`. You should check if it's valid before proceeeding.

These are declared, but never used. Do you really need these lines?

```
int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
```

If you do need these lines you must check if the index is out of range before you try to declare them.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        groupBoxPenghuni.Visible = false;
        groupBoxStaff.Visible = false;
        groupBoxRoom.Visible = false;
        groupBoxDPenghuni.Visible = true;
        groupBoxPenghasilan.Visible = false;
        GroupBox_AddResident_Resident.Visible = false;
        GroupBox_AddResident_Room.Visible = false;
        GroupBox_AddResident1.Visible = false;
        GroupBox_DeleteResident_Resident.Visible = false;
        GroupBox_DeleteResident1.Visible = false;
        GroupBox_Resident.Visible = false;
        GroupBox_Update_Room.Visible = false;
        GroupBox_UpdateResident1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never use this code
`int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];`
then just deleted it and finally the program didn't break.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you have to check in CellContentClick event:

```
if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex!=-1)
{
// do something
}
```

if e.RowIndex is -1 that menas you clicked a column header
The same will be true for row headers